# CFBundleShortVersionString Returning Wrong Version

Tags: ios, swift, version

We compare the current version of the app via `CFBundleShortVersionString` to a version on our backend to figure out if we want to force the user to update. For some reason, within the first 24 hours of releasing a new version, *CFBundleShortVersionString returns the wrong version*. We have tried multiple solutions so far but none have seemed to work. Here's a simplified version of what we use to compare:

```
func needToUpdate(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let currentVersion = Foundation.Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
          let currentVersionInt = Int(currentVersion.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))
             else { completion(false); return }  

    let versionInt = Int((versionObject.version ?? "0").replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")) ?? 0

    completion(currentVersionInt < versionInt)  
}
```

Also, this issue only happens once the app is released to the app store, so we cannot debug it in xcode. We have tried releasing the update at midnight but users in the morning still call in saying they have updated the app but the popup still appears. Any idea as to what's causing this?

Comment: what is a value of `versionObject.value` ?

Comment: i hope there are not things like multiple decimal like 1.0.0

Comment: `versionObject.version` is equal to the most-current app version, ex. "1.10.2"

Comment: I'm also seeing logs where the CFBundleShortVersionString seems to be returning wrong values.  Did you ever come to any conclusions about this?

Comment: This could be related to the "Manage Version and Build Number" feature in Xcode 13, which had a bug until Xcode 15.

From the Xcode 15 release notes: "Fixed: Resolved an issue where the “Manage version and build number” distribution option in Xcode and Xcode Cloud overwrote the version and build number of framework dependencies in apps. When distributing an app, framework dependencies retain their original version and build numbers. (106869375)"

Answer (score 2):

Do not convert versions to int, as it can fail on version number greater 9, e.g. 1.10.0 becomes 1100, which is greater than 2.1.0, which is converted to 210

you can compare the resulting string directly with .compare() like "1.10.0".compare("2.1.0") which returns a ComparisonResult

Comment: We are having this issue changing from for example 1.12.2 to 1.12.3. After the code I included in the question we check to see if it is a major update (ex. 1.12.x to 1.13.x) which compares the first and second value (ex. 1 v. 1 and 12 v. 13). Good call though on converting versions to ints -- I'll definitely make sure to update my code with your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't solve the current issue.